# how to configure cors on nginx?

Tags: nginx, cors, cross-browser, cross-domain, nginx-config

I have configured cors on nginx according to the instructions but that didn't fix the problem.

```
#Disable IFRAME
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE";
add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *;


add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

#Prevent Cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

#Prevent MIME-sniffing
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
```

The result is still not fixed:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

There are few minor things that I can suggest for troubleshooting your current issue:

1. There is multiple entry for header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Please remove any extras.
2. There is missing colon (:) and trailing comma (,) chars for entry for header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods". Please fix it.
3. Make sure nginx server get restarted or stopped/started.

Comment: thank you, i have corrected it as per your suggestion but still not solved the problem :(

Comment: I made quick reference to few sites on how to enable CORS in nginx and noticed that there is NO colon separator (:) when setting them in ngnix config file. The colon (:) only appear when they were trying to demonstrate that the settings were successfully applied in the request header section.

Comment: Hi  Hamid Se,

Thanks for answering
I modified the code as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/b68oza9u/

But it still can't work

Comment: Please take a look and adjust accordlingly.

https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Comment: Based on the given screenshots above, I assumed that you're running a single instance of nginx as webserver (and not as proxy) with 2 virtual hosts; 1 for api at port 80 and 1 for client at port 9013. I hope you've set the cors header at the right server config which at the api.

Comment: Yes I'm configuring it just as you assume. Cors I configured at server api. But I also tried configuring the nginx.conf file and tried configuring the client config file as well port 9013. The result is not good.